# Qt - Creating a dark overlay to apply on top of other widgets with animation

Tags: c++, qt

I want to be able to create a dark overlay on top of other widgets that can be turned on or off with animation. I managed to get this to work.

But I think I'm doing it in a wrong and inefficient way; for example, in `OverlayWidget` class I use `setAttribute` multiple times to enable and disable the `MouseEvents` and I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do.

So I will be grateful if someone can help me see how to improve this code.

Here is working code:

### `main.cpp`

```cpp
#include "OverlayTest.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    OverlayTest w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

### `OverlayTest.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "OverlayWidget.h"

class OverlayTest : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OverlayTest(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    QWidget* central_widget;
    QPushButton* button;
    QVBoxLayout* layout;
    OverlayWidget* overlay;

};
```

### `OverlayTest.cpp`

```cpp
#include "OverlayTest.h"

OverlayTest::OverlayTest(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(600, 400);

    // central layout
    central_widget = new QWidget(this);
    central_widget->setObjectName("CentralWidget");
    central_widget->setStyleSheet(R"(
        QWidget#CentralWidget {
            background-color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
            border-radius: 8;
        })"
    );
    setCentralWidget(central_widget);

    // main layout
    layout = new QVBoxLayout(central_widget);
    layout->setSpacing(5);
    layout->setContentsMargins(9, 9, 9, 9);

    // button
    button = new QPushButton("Enable Overlay", central_widget);
    layout->addWidget(button);

    // setup overlay widget
    overlay = new OverlayWidget(central_widget, 250);
    overlay->resize(central_widget->size());

    // connect button to the overlay
    connect(button, &QPushButton::released, this, [=] {
        overlay->show(true);
        button->setText("Tap anyway to deactive the overlay");
    });
    connect(overlay, &OverlayWidget::pressed, this, [=] {   // for when the overlay is active, and user want
        overlay->show(false);                               // to deactive it by tapping on it
        button->setText("Enable Overlay");
    });
}
```

My Overlay widget:

### `OverlayWidget.h`

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QGraphicsOpacityEffect>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class OverlayWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit OverlayWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr, const int duration = 370);
    void show(const bool& show = true);

signals:
    void pressed();

private:
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect fade_effect;
    QPropertyAnimation animation;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* ev) override;
    bool event(QEvent* ev) override;

private:
    void newParent();
};
```

### `OverlayWidget.cpp`

```cpp
#include "OverlayWidget.h"
#include <QPainter>

OverlayWidget::OverlayWidget(QWidget* parent, const int duration)
    : QWidget{ parent }
    , fade_effect(this)
    , animation(&fade_effect, "opacity")
{
    setPalette(Qt::transparent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    newParent();
    setGraphicsEffect(&fade_effect);
    animation.setStartValue(0.0);
    animation.setEndValue(1.0);
    animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutQuint);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    setVisible(false);
    setEnabled(false);
}

void OverlayWidget::newParent()
{
    if (!parent()) return;
    parent()->installEventFilter(this);
    raise();
}

bool OverlayWidget::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* ev)
{
    if (obj == parent()) {
        if (ev->type() == QEvent::Resize)
            resize(static_cast<QResizeEvent*>(ev)->size());
        else if (ev->type() == QEvent::ChildAdded)
            raise();
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, ev);
}

bool OverlayWidget::event(QEvent* ev)
{
    if (ev->type() == QEvent::ParentAboutToChange) {
        if (parent()) parent()->removeEventFilter(this);
    }
    else if (ev->type() == QEvent::ParentChange)
        newParent();
    return QWidget::event(ev);
}

void OverlayWidget::show(const bool& show)
{
    animation.stop();
    animation.setStartValue(animation.currentValue());
    animation.setEndValue(show ? 1.0 : 0.0); // show or hide
    animation.start();
    if (show) {
        setVisible(true);
        setEnabled(true);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, false);
    }
    else {
        // setVisible(false);
        setEnabled(false);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
    }
}

void OverlayWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 150)));
    painter.setOpacity(50);
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.drawRoundedRect(rect(), 8.0, 8.0); // becasue my frame is round
}

void OverlayWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        emit pressed();
}
```